# Very high CPU >95% after we migrate to PostgreSQL version 16.1

Tags: amazon-rds, postgresql-16

We recently migrated RDS PostgreSQL from 11.22 to 16.1 but we notice queries are taking more time and most of the time CPU is > 95%. does anybody else faced this issue? any recommendations to improve performance?

We also tried by ending the sessions but we still notice ~60% CPU. in previous version most of the time it was < 10% but after upgrade we continuously see high CPU. Any best practices post upgrade to improve performance?

Instance class : db.t4g.medium

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

We did the following and now CPU is much better:

1. Reindexing
2. vacuum analyze